# .htaccess conflicting

Tags: css, .htaccess

i have following .htaccess
RewriteEngine On

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,20})/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ index\.php?page=$1&s=$2&o=$3 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,20})/([^/]+)?$ index\.php?page=$1&s=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,20})/?$ index\.php?page=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,20})?$ index\.php?page=$1 [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404
```

it displays mu url as localhost/mysite/home for first perimeter and its going fine but when my url is localhost/mysite/home/user, whole look of page is disturbed i.e. no css and image is included here
can any one please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are probably loading your css by specifing a relative path (i.e not starting with a "/"). specify the path to the css to be absolute, and you'll be fine.

Edit:
I'm putting the answer here for better formatting than the comments: 
You should specify that existing files should not be rewriten:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f

RewriteRule .* - [L]`

Put this as your first rule.

Comment: you should also specify that existing files should not be rewriten: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f RewriteRule .* -`

Comment: did you start it with "/mysite/home" ? since your site is not in the web root. "/" means web root.

Comment: i included my css like <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" /> but while viewing source, i am having the following source <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/mysite/css/style.css" />

Comment: please see the edit I put in the answer. you are probably rewriting everything (including css/images) with your .htaccess, so the request for the css ends up as index.php?page=css&s=style.css or something similar. also, as mentioned before, you need to insert your css like so: `<link href="/mysite/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reason is because, in your index.php file, scripts and css files are given relative locations. e.g: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />` What you have to do is, change the locations to absolute paths. e.g: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/mysite/style.css" />` Hope this would help you.

Comment: i included my css like <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" /> but while viewing source, i am having the following source <link rel="stylesheet" href="localhost/mysite/css/style.css"; />